# Inheritance failing when class name is prefixed with module name

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

I'm having a really weird problem with inheritance within a module. Here's my code:

```
module MyModule
    class MyModule.ErrorClass < StandardError

    end
end
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
myfile.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'
        class MyModule.ErrorClass < StandardError
                               ^
myfile.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

However, when I change it to this:

```
module MyModule
    class ErrorClass < StandardError

    end
end
```

it runs fine with no errors.

Comment: by nesting you get the prefix for free, ie `MyModule::ErrorClass`, that is valid ruby syntax - in your first example it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to repeat the module name as you did in your first example. And furthermore using a `.` instead of `::` to separate the module name from the class name is not valid Ruby.

Just use

```
module MyModule
  class ErrorClass < StandardError
    # ...
  end
end
```

or

```
class MyModule::ErrorClass < StandardError # note the colons
  # ...
end
```